# Оценка алгоритма поиска гамильтонова пути

Tags: графы

До каких границ (грубо) осмыслено применение алгоритма поиска гамильтонова пути в полугамильтоновом графе на современных персоналках? Допустим, если есть граф из 400 вершин по 10-40 рёбер из каждой это вполне реалистично или уже труба? Если в 2 раза больше? Или при таких цифрах стоит на этапе реализации сразу задуматься о эвристических оптимизациях?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, конечно, спасибо, поправил

Comment: Не претендуя на истинность, я пытался прикинуть сложность полного перебора для худшего случая, у меня получается порядка O(N!), где N∈[min(d(V)); |V|]. С факториальной сложностью труба обычно наступает уже на двух-трёх десятках... Но лучше всё же проверить на практике...